# iReport not launching on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, ireport

I have iReport Designer versions 3.7.2, 4.5, 4.7.1, & 5.6.0 installed on my mac. Since upgrading to Yosemite yesterday, I cannot launch any of them.

In the console I get:

"10/18/14 11:30:32.754 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000013.ireport[37460]) Service exited with abnormal code: 2"

Not sure how to get around this, I'm sure it is something fairly simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the fix is to install "Java for OS X 2014-001" from Apple. I did this and iReport now launches for me.

Download here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Answer (score 24):

The solution for me was to change the content of the file **ireport.conf** located in the directory 
**/Applications/Jaspersoft iReport Designer.app/Contents/Resources/ireport/etc** under the line with this text

**# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome  switch**

i uncommented the next line and changed it for this
**jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home"**
and now is working.

Comment: Worked perfect! I think is the best solution, not to install Java 6 :-P

Comment: I can confirm that this still works on High Sierra using iReport 5.6.0 and Java 8 `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: This seems to have stopped working on MacOS Mojave with Java 8.0.1011 (`jdk1.8.0_1011`)